# Can I use command line to set developer verified for gerrit server changes

Tags: git, build, automation, gerrit

I have been tasked to write a tool that queries open changes for a given git projects. Next it uses the tip of tree and the open changes to create a build and test. And if build and testing goes fine then set a developer-verified on the change.

By reading some available documentation I am able to query open changes form gerrit and pull those as required. But I need help regarding how I can set the developer verified bit.

Is it possible to use something like the [gerrit query](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html) to set the developer verified?
I did read about [gerrit review](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-review.html) but I am not able to understand how to use my change numbers that I retrieved using [gerrit query](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html).

Comment: Suppose `aaa` is a user in the gerrit group of `Administrators`. `ssh -p ${port} aaa@${host} gerrit set-reviewers ${change} -a ${reviewer} -p ${project}` to add the reviewer. `ssh -p ${port} ${reviewer}@${host} gerrit review ${change} --code-review +2` to review with +2. `${reviewer}` can be `aaa`. Besides you can run gerrit restapis to do the job.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thanks for the suggesting the rest apis. I never thought thats an option. Will explore that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the "developer-verified" label using the "gerrit review" command you need to execute:

```
ssh gerrit gerrit review --label developer-verified=VALUE COMMIT|CHANGEID,PATCHSET
```

Examples:

```
ssh gerrit gerrit review --label developer-verified=+1 9a56f1ebe1edaef9a2c86b78da6ce4f66ff3eb53

ssh gerrit gerrit review --label developer-verified=-1 40666,2
```

To get the Commit or the ChangeId+Patchset of the change using the "gerrit query" command you need to use the "--current-patch-set" parameter:

```
ssh gerrit gerrit query --current-patch-set status:open project:PROJECT

change I5d196415aa48791adf60b7bc4b9b00280e992c9b
  project: PROJECT
  branch: master
  id: I5d196415aa48791adf60b7bc4b9b00280e992c9b
  number: 40666
  ...
  currentPatchSet:
    number: 2
    revision: 9a56f1ebe1edaef9a2c86b78da6ce4f66ff3eb53
  ...
```

The Commit will be shown in the "revision" field and the ChangeId+Patchset at the "number" fields.

Comment: thanks for the exact solution for my current approach.